# swiftでNotification actionを 2パターン作りたい

Tags: swift, xcode, iphone, notification

以下のサイトを参考にして、通知をスライドしたら、アクションが表示させるアプリをSwiftで書いてみました。
[SwiftのNotificationでHello, Worldして、アクションを3つ作ってみた](http://qiita.com/kiiita/items/453426e3873e58dc8768)

これを応用して、状況に応じてアクションAとアクションB、アクションAとアクションCの二つのパターン表示できるようにしたいです。この画像のように２パターンできるようにしたいです。

そう思って以下のコードを書いたのですが、これだとtaskCategoryだけしか表示されません。
２つのパターン表示できるようにするにはどうしたらいいでしょうか。お願いします。

自分が書いたコードでは、アクションはそれぞれLATER、DELETE、OPENにしてあります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Actions
    let leterAction:UIMutableUserNotificationAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    leterAction.identifier = "LETER_ACTION"
    leterAction.title = "Leter"

    leterAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background
    leterAction.destructive = false
    leterAction.authenticationRequired = true

    let deleteAction:UIMutableUserNotificationAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    deleteAction.identifier = "DELETE_ACTION"
    deleteAction.title = "Delete"

    deleteAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background
    deleteAction.destructive = false
    deleteAction.authenticationRequired = true

    let openAction:UIMutableUserNotificationAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    openAction.identifier = "OPEN_ACTION"
    openAction.title = "Open"

    openAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background
    openAction.destructive = false
    openAction.authenticationRequired = true

    // category

    let todoCategory:UIMutableUserNotificationCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
    todoCategory.identifier = "TODO_CATEGORY"
    let taskCategory:UIMutableUserNotificationCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
    taskCategory.identifier = "TASK_CATEGORY"

    let openActions:NSArray = [openAction, deleteAction]
    let taskActions:NSArray = [leterAction, deleteAction]

    todoCategory.setActions(openActions as? [UIUserNotificationAction], forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Default)
    taskCategory.setActions(taskActions as? [UIUserNotificationAction], forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Default)

    // NSSet of all our categories
    let category1:NSSet = NSSet(objects: todoCategory)
    let category2:NSSet = NSSet(objects: taskCategory)
    let types: UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Sound]

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: types, categories: category1 as? Set<UIUserNotificationCategory>))
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: types, categories: category2 as? Set<UIUserNotificationCategory>))

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> そう思って以下のコードを書いたのですが、これだとtaskCategoryだけしか表示されません。

原因は下記の部分の`registerUserNotificationSettings(_: UIUserNotificationSettings)`のところで、最初に`todoCategory`を登録したあと、`taskCategory`で上書きしてしまっているからですね。

```
let category1:NSSet = NSSet(objects: todoCategory)
let category2:NSSet = NSSet(objects: taskCategory)
let types: UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Sound]

UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: types, categories: category1 as? Set<UIUserNotificationCategory>))
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: types, categories: category2 as? Set<UIUserNotificationCategory>))
```

カテゴリは`Set`を使って複数登録できるという仕組みなので、`Set`に１件ずつ入れてしまっていいては意味がありません。

`Set`オブジェクトに複数のカテゴリを格納して、複数のカテゴリを登録する、という処理にしなければなりません。

たとえば下記のようにします。
ついでに`NSSet`を使うとキャストが必要になるので、`Set`に変更しました。

```
let types: UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Sound]
let categories = Set(arrayLiteral: todoCategory, taskCategory)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: types, categories: categories))
```